# Linq to entities DbQuery object is failing hard

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I wonder if anyone can shed some light on what may be happening here. I'm using C#, MVC, with entity framework.

So I run these two lines of code:

```
var booboo = _context.AppItems.Where(ai => ai.id == 101);
var sql = booboo.ToString();
```

And I get some strange behavior. The booboo.ToString() method hangs, thus failing. Nothing about the booboo DbQuery object works properly in fact.
I'm having similar problems all over the code with my AppItem entity (AppItems is DbSet as you might guess). Entity Framework appears to be unable to construct a query for the AppItem entity.

**Edit:**
I wasn't patient enough! After leaving it for a very long time, I do get the following exception:
"Message=Internal error: An expression services limit has been reached. Please look for potentially complex expressions in your query, and try to simplify them."
Interestingly that's a Sql.Client exception, which I wasn't expecting.

Here's what the AppItem class looks like:

```
public class AppItem : Domain.Item
{
    public int? UserProfileId { get; set; }
    public virtual UserProfile UpdatedByUser { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(50)] 
    public String Type { get; set;}

    public DateTime UpdatedDate { get; set;}

    // flags
    public virtual ICollection<ItemFlag> Flags { get; set; }

    // actions
    public virtual ICollection<ItemAction> Actions { get; set; }

    // notes
    public virtual ICollection<Note> Notes { get; set; }
}
```

Domain Item contains a primary key field (id) and a few other fields.

The Note / ItemAction / ItemFlag Classes there all inherit from AppItem, so perhaps some sort of circular referencing is to blame?

Other items can be queried just fine. For example, I have numerous classes that inherit from AppItem (like ItemFlag, ItemAction and Note) and I can query all of these just fine.
So, where Members is DbSet and Member inherits from AppItem:

```
var foofoo = _context.Members.Where(ai => ai.id = 101);
var sql = foofoo.ToString();
```

This Works fine; foofoo.ToString() returns the constructed SQL and everything appears to be in order.

It seems really bizarre to me, there's no error message or anything, the application just hangs when it tries to query AppItems. The table exists in the database, but that doesn't matter because we aren't getting as far as querying the database, we are failing to construct a query in the first place.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found what the problem was.
I'm using Table-per-Type for inheritance. With AppItem being a base type, the SQL query it generates for querying it is huge (several thousand lines long in this case) and causes problems.
So basically, you need to avoid querying on base types that have more than a few types inheriting from them when using Table-per-Type.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that your query is meant to return 1 item.

Add `.FirstOrDefault();` onto the end of your query to only return one item (your current query returns an IQueriable of type AppItems)

The Entity Framework does not execute the query until needed, so in your code it will execute the query when the .ToString() method is called.

Try this:

```
var booboo = _context.AppItems.Where(ai => ai.id == 101).FirstOrDefault();

if (booboo != null)
{
    var sql = booboo.ToString();

    //etc
}
```

Comment: Yes, I know all that.
If I run the code you post, the application hangs on the first line. It doesn't matter what query I run, if I try to run any method on any DbQuery<AppItem> object, whether that method is FirstOrDefault() or ToString(), the application hangs.

Comment: Hmm.. have you tried putting a try-catch block around it? It seems to be ailing silently...

Comment: Also is the database on a local server? or hosted elsewhere?

Comment: A try-catch doesn't help because it is hanging, producing no exception. So it just gets stuck on the same line inside the try block.
The database is on a separate server in the same room. I have no problems accessing the database from my development machine and running sql queries against it. I have no problems running sql queries against the AppItem table.
The database can't be the issue because it's not getting that far. The DbQuery object can't even produce a SQL string without hanging.

Comment: I got an exception when I left it long enough. I edited the original question and put the message there.

Comment: Aaah right, I thought it might be a Connection Timeout Exception of some sort but appears not, sorry I am unsure what to do there!